# Warning: "Expected type 'Type[ParentClass]', got 'ChildClass' instead" when typehinted as Type[ParentClass]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can you please explain, why PyCharm gives me warning `Expected type 'Type[BaseObject]', got 'LongObject' instead` when I pass an instance of a subclass of the typehinted parent class into a function?

I use Python 3.9, Pycharm 2021.2.3

The code is here:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Type


@dataclass
class BaseObject:
    name: str
    color: str


@dataclass
class LongObject(BaseObject):
    length: int


@dataclass
class WideObject(BaseObject):
    width: int


def print_object_name(obj: Type[BaseObject]):
    print(obj.name)


long_thing = LongObject(name='LONG', color='RED', length=42)
print_object_name(long_thing)

wide_thing = WideObject(name='LONG', color='RED', width=88)
print_object_name(wide_thing)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your type annotation here is wrong:

```
def print_object_name(obj: Type[BaseObject]):
    print(obj.name)
```

To annotate `obj` as an *instance* of type `BaseObject` just do:

```
def print_object_name(obj: BaseObject):
    print(obj.name)
```

The `Type` type is used when an object is itself a type rather than an instance of that type, e.g. if you were to do:

```
print_object_name(LongObject)
```

the argument would have a type of `Type[LongObject]`, which is a subtype of `Type[BaseObject]` just like `LongObject` is a subtype of `BaseObject`.

Comment: But how should I make clear in a typehint, that function can accept not only ParentClass instance, but also ChildClass instances?

Comment: If `ChildClass` is a child of `ParentClass` then all you need to do is annotate it as `ParentClass` and it will accept `ChildClass` as well.  That's just how inheritance works.  In your example, annotating `obj` as `BaseObject` permits arguments of any `BaseObject` type, including `LongObject` and `WideObject`.  Did you get an error when you tried annotating it that way?

Comment: no, when I did it your way there was no error. Thank you for the explanation.